# Remove null attributes from GeoJSON

Tags: geojson

I used the following command to reproject a GeoJSON from lat/lon to 3857:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" results_3857.json -t_srs "EPSG:3857" results.json
```

Unexpectedly, the resulting file was 5 times larger than the original.

Turns out the resulting file contains all properties for each feature, while the original contained only those properties that were not `null`.

For example the original might have had a properties objects that look like this:

```
..."properties": { a: 1, d: 2, f: 1 }....
..."properties": { b: 1, c: 2, d: 2 }...
```

while the newly reprojected file has converted them to look like this:

```
..."properties": { a: 1, b: null, c: null, d: 2, e: null, f: 1 }...
..."properties": { a: null, b: 1, c: 2, d: 2, e: null, f: null }...
```

I don't want these extra `null` entries in my reprojected GeoJSON.

And so my question is this:

How can I remove those properties that have `null` values from the GeoJSON?

Is there some flag I can use in the ogr2ogr command?
Maybe there is a subsequent gdal command I can use to remove those attributes that have a null value?

Comment: You could eliminate the "null" values with a regex and iterate through file. Keep in mind this will cause problems when when filtering, styling, or querying a file. Features should contain the same field names throughout.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such flag for GeoJSON driver. It should be doable because GDAL does not write null attributes into GML. I recommend to file a GDAL feature request.

Comment: This has been fixed in GDAL 2.2.0

Answer (score 3):

for a GeoJSON featureCollection, you could do something like this:

```
var myGeoJSON = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "hi",
        "num": 9,
        "other": null
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          23.203125,
          53.12040528310657
        ]
      }
    }
    //,....
  ]
}

for(var i=0; i<myGeoJSON.features.length; i++){
    var obj = myGeoJSON.features[i].properties;
    for(var key in obj){
        var attrName = key;
        var attrValue = obj[key];
        if (!attrValue){
          delete obj[key];
        }
    }
}
```

i posted a sample [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/remove-geojson-nulls.html)

Comment: Thanks John.  I was hoping for an ogr command line solution...but perhaps it doesn't exist...

Comment: @sfletche It may be fixed in GDAL 2.2.0